# NightwatchJS - Response from elements command with chromedriver standalone

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am receiving different results in responses when using `client.elements` command, comparing ChromeDriver standalone execution of the tests and while running on Selenium Server. Here is the output from selenium:

```
{ ELEMENT: '18' }
```

And here is the output from ChromeDriver:

```
{ ELEMENT: '0.3628625391025624-9' }
```

Can someone please explain why is this difference taking place in ELEMENT'S ID ?

Comment: Seems an implementation difference, but does it matter?  An element reference is an opaque string (although in practice I've seen Selenium use sequential numeric IDs per session.)  It can change from one test run to the next, if your page structure and/or test cases vary.

Comment: Mostly just wanted to know for sure.. Yes I've noticed the same thing with selenium itself